# Prevent logged in user variable from changing in different context in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication, django-users

I'm using Django 1.8.4 and Django-registration-redux for handling user registration. My problem is:

when a user logged in, i.e. james, I want to show his username in toolbar. But the problem is when I visit another user's profile,i.e. mike, the username in toolbar also changes to mike. Which is absolutely forbidden.

I'm getting logged in user as an object in my views to check if the logged in user is same as user's profile is currently visited.

I'm not sure if I should prevent request.user to change in different contexts or there's a problem in my codes:

urls.py

```
url(r'^users/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', UserProfileDetailView.as_view(), name="profile"),
```

views.py

```
class UserProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model       = get_user_model()
    slug_field  = "username"
    template_name = "user_detail.html"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        user    = super(UserProfileDetailView, self).get_object(queryset)
        UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return user
```

base.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'link_create' %}">Submit Link</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'profile' slug=user.username %}"><b>{{ user.username }}</b></a> 
  {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">Register</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a> 
{% endif %}
```

user_detail.html

```
{% if object == request.user and request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p><a href='{% url "edit_profile" %}'>Edit My Profile</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Does the edit profile link gets displayed on a different(not the logged-in user) user's  profile page.?

Comment: Why are you returning a user object in your `UserProfileDetailView`?

Comment: @RahulGupta No, edit profile link shows up only for logged in user, who is visiting his own profile page.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid To check the current logged in user, with user's profile page, and show the edit-profile link if they are the same.

Comment: You don't need to do that - the current logged in user is always available to you as `request.user`. Your view should return the profile object.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid How can I compare logged in user with the slug of that user's profile then? I did this since I didn't know how to do this comparison.

Comment: I've removed get_object function, but still have same problem. On each /users/username page, the username in toolbar changes to the current page users instead of being fixed to logged in username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 users in your context:

1. `object` (or `user` - `DetailView` will also return current object on lowercased model name) this is user you're viewing
2. `request.user` - this is current logged in user

You've used `user.name` in toolbar instead of `request.user.name`. That is causing issues.